# How to split folder with images into train, val and test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am using colab and I have a folder with images. How to split them into three folders with images with random splitting? I want there to be 0.8 in train, 0.1 in val and 0.1 in test. I tried splitfolders library:

```
splitfolders.ratio("content/data", output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .1, .1), group_prefix=None)
```

but new folder didn't appear. and its not clear what would their names be. How to do that? Are there any other solutions?

Pytorch solutions are very welcomed

Comment: Did you mount this files from google drive? I just tried it here with some random data and it worked.

Comment: @DouglasFerreira no with wget from dropbox

Comment: Try to run without the content prefix and make sure that the folder structure is labeled and filled correctly

Comment: did it work? any updates?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your computer.

I'm using this code in my project

```
import splitfolders 

#### input dataset that want to split
input_folder = 'D:/Raw_DS'  

output_folder= 'D:/Splitted_DS'

splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, output= output_folder, seed=1337, ratio = (0.8, 0.1, 0.1))
```